# How can I specify the position (X,Y) of the touch in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I tried to use MR.Gestures, but I do not want to buy anything. Does anybody know how to use the TapGestureRecognizer class in this respect?

Comment: Honestly Mr Gestures is probably your best bet, because otherwise you have to implement some fairly sophisticated platform-specific methods to get at the detail (which is what Mr Gestures does for you, and probably better than you would do yourself). Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Create custom class to handle the logic and use custom renderer , check : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/253375/#Comment_253375

Comment: I still do not know it..

Comment: Have you tried the code in that link ? What's the exact problem ?